# Adding json result to a form action url

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, json

I want to add the result coming back from the json to the end of my form action.

This is the code I have now

```
$('.listAllBugs').append('<tr class="table-stroke"><td>'+bugDetails+'</td><td><a href="#edit">Edit</a></tr>');
```

The form is in the `#edit` area. Which has the form as

```
<form id="users-form" action="" method="post">
```

The action url is the one I want to change.. Ideas would be helpful!

Comment: what is the json that is coming back?

Comment: The json is just some text, but  i need a number from the json to be added onto the end of a url path

Comment: The json response! sorry comes back as bug_id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this will set the form action to a new value:

```
$('form#users-form').attr('action', '');
```

Comment: so place this under the previous $ sign and have it so its like $('form#users-form').attr('action', '+bug_id+');

Comment: the answers yes, It does:)